# How can I be sure all collections have been populated?

Tags: php, javascript, backbone.js, laravel

I need to populate all my app's collections before presenting any view. The problem is, however, sometimes I have to refresh the page a few times before I see that all have been populated.

As an example, sometimes the rooms collection is completely empty when I know that there are rooms in the database. In this case, the server response is empty.

Here is a stripped down implementation:

```
(function() {
    window.rooms = new App.Collections.Rooms();

    $.when(rooms.fetch()).done(function() {
        window.router = new App.Router;
        Backbone.history.start();
    });
}());
```

This is the code that returns rooms from the server:

```
public function get_index() {
    $rooms = Room::where('id_hostel', '=', Session::get('id_hostel'))->get();
    $response = array();

    foreach($rooms as $room) {
        $response[] = $room->attributes;
    }

    return json_encode($response);
}
```

Actually I don't know if the error is on the client side or in the Laravel RESTful service I've programmed. How can I fix this intermittent problem?

Comment: This is almost certainly a server side issue if the request returned is empty. Check any error logs for invalid queries or other errors, and dump out `$response` from the server to see what it contains. I'm going to make a guess that it's your session specifically if it takes a few reloads to get working. That said, Laravel should handle sessions correctly.

Comment: Try adding a success callback to your fetch. If you log the response there, what do you get? `rooms.fetch({success: function(model, response) {
  console.log(response);
}});`

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to handle this if you refer - [Collection fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)

First way is already mentioned by *Sidney* and that's using `fetch` and `success` callback.

Second way is using `events`, which, in my opinion is better because you can decouple code easier with better readability.

```
var rooms = window.rooms = new App.Collections.Rooms();
    rooms.fetch();
    ...
    rooms.on('sync', someFunction);
```

or

```
var rooms = window.rooms = new App.Collections.Rooms();
    rooms.fetch({reset: true});
    ...
    rooms.on('reset', someFunction);


someFunction () {
    window.router = new App.Router;
    Backbone.history.start();
}
```

Tho I must say this is not the preferred "Backbone way" of doing things. I strongly encourage you to read [Backbone Patterns](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/)